# SublimeLinter for PHP

Tags: php, sublimetext2, sublimelinter

I cannot get SublimeLinter to work with Sublime Text 2.  I have node.js installed and wamp installed and my user settings for SublimeLinter is as follows:

```
{
    "sublimelinter_executable_map":
    {
        "javascript":"C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe",
        "css":"C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe",
        "php":"C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/php.exe"
    }
}
```

I have created a file on my desktop called 'cool.php' with the following code:

```
<?php
function hel()
{
    error->
}
?>
```

But nothing shows up to tell me that the 'error->' is incorrect.  What am I doing wrong?

**Side Note:** In the readme of SublimeLinter it says '* PHP - syntax check via `php -l`'.  What does that mean?

Comment: Did you do a `php --help`?

Comment: Do you mean in the sublimetext console?

Comment: No, in a terminal, or how do you call that in Windows? If I do that, it says: "-l               Syntax check only (lint)".

Comment: In command prompt?  I'm really not sure what you are talking about -

Comment: Yes, on the command line. There you'll see what `php -l` means.

Comment: So in order to be able to have linting in PHP, I have to be running a web server on my local machine?

Comment: No, you should have PHP installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Linux which was caused by ST2 was opening PHP files as a different file type.

To fix it, open a .php file then click `View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as... > PHP`.

It might also be that you need to use double backslash instead of forward slashes:

```
{
    "sublimelinter_executable_map":
    {
        "javascript":"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe",
        "css":"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe",
        "php":"C:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.3.13\\php.exe"
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it matters but my Windows settings use double backslashes and work.

Answer (score 0):

To check php -l go to the start menu and type 'command' then open a command prompt and type

```
php -l
```

If you get an error saying php is not a recognised command then you need to add php to your system path.
Right click on 'my computer' and properties -> advanced system settings -> environment variables -> system variables -> path Add the path on the end separated by a ; 
    ;C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/php.exe 
if you want to use node for js hinting then add the path to node here as well.
Close the prompt by typing exit then open a new one and type php -l again.
Close sublime text then reopen it and check if the linter is working.